# Reload JS function after reload DIV

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

the context: I have a div (#container) with js inside that return planet rise and planet set.

When I reload my div (#container) like this:

```
$("#container").load(location.href + " #container");
```

It doesn't reload my js inside it and therefore does not display planet rise and planet set.

I try to reload the js function that calcul planet rise and planet set (loadPlanetComponent()) ,like this:

```
function loadTonight() {

        $("#container").load(location.href + " #container");
  
        loadPlanetComponent();
    }
```

But when I do that, it reload my function before or at the same time it reload my div so variables (planet rise and planet set) are not displayed.

Also I try 2 things:

- Put a delay to reload loadPlanetComponent(), but sometimes, when the div takes time to load, it doesn't work
- Wait the reload of the div but it does'nt work.

Comment: jQuery's `load()` function accepts a callback function to perform after loading is complete. So all you'd have to do is: `$("#container").load(location.href + " #container", function(){ loadPlanetComponent(); });`. Which translates to: Load the content, when finished, execute this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's [load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) function accepts a callback function to execute after the status is set to complete:

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed.

So to solve the issue, you simply need to provide a callback function to your `load()` function:

```js
$("#container").load(location.href + " #container", function(){ 
    loadPlanetComponent();
});
```